# Should DTOs use inheritance or composition

Tags: java, design-patterns, soa, composition, dto

In SOA if a few DTO classes have some fields that are repeated across. Is it better to use Composition or Inheritance so there is not repetition OR just use one DTO class that encapsulates all fields.As my DTO classes grow I see lot of repetitive field names and Sonar report is crying fowl. What is the best approach(or an alternative).

e.g.

```
public class DocDto{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String docType
}

public class DocReviewDto{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private String comment;
}
```

Comment: If a DTO has a "is a" relationship with another DTO, then should it use inheritance?  If a DTO has a "has a" relationship with another, then should it use composition?  These are the real questions you want to be asking.  Inheritance or composition are not ends unto themselves.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The "one DTO class" approach is almost certainly bad. It smells like a God Class. Many pundits excoriate DTOs altogether. You could inherit from some base class, but for value objects it's not really sensible. Same for composition. It makes your code more complicated. When debugging the "DocReview" flow, you'd have to look at two, three, or more DTO classes to understand it with either approach. Bleagh! Also, each DTO is typically in a separate semantic domain: "Doc" is not "DocReview". So the apparent "common" elements are not actually common at all. They just share an implementation type; their meanings are quite different.

When the member type is inherently composite, for example if many domains share the concept of an `Identifier`, you could make that a type for composition into the DTOs for those domains. In your example, you might have

```
public class Identifier {
  long id; // should be a 'String', actually
  String name;
}

public class Doc {
  private Identifier identifier;
  private String docType
}

public class DocReview {
  private Identifier identifier;
  private String status;
  private String comment;
}
```

The key here is that `Identifier` is semantically equivalent in both domains, so it makes sense to have it as a common type. Otherwise you wouldn't do that.

Sidebar: "Dto" (or "DTO") as a suffix is not good naming, really.

Comment: What Lew said... in general avoid inheritance and favor composition. Inheritance is a good practice for polymorphism (Car -> Ferrari -> Model XXX)

Comment: Extracting out common fields into a class and using composition makes sense. I agree naming convention xxxDto is awkward, but we have entities named as e.g Doc so need some way to differentiate. You said -Many pundits excoriate DTOs altogether - why is that and what alternatives do we have?